# How to create reverse-lookup file for BIND that points to some networks?

Tags: dns, bind

I am try to create a reverse-lookup file in BIND, but I need it to point to many networks not just one.

I have three networks that connected to the same bind server, `192.168.3` and `192.168.4` and `192.168.1`. I would like that in one reverse-lookup file I could refer to all of the clients at the three networks.
Currently I have no idea on how to write that zone file, what I have is:

```
168.192.in-addr.arpa. SOA dns1.mynetwork.unix admin.mynetwork.unix
1.4.168.192 IN PTR  dns1.mynetwork.unix 
11.3  IN PTR client.mynetwork.unix
```

When I start the bind server, it gives me an error message on the log file at `/var/log/messeges/` that says:

`loading from master file named.168.192 faild: not a valid number`

I have omitted the other unrelated (IMO) stuff from the configuration file.

To sum it up, i would concise the question to be, is it possible to create a reverse dns file (in bind) that can point to a different networks ? if yes what do i need to change in the example above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SOA record you posted is incorrect; it needs to be of the form:

`zone  IN SOA auth-server. admin.address (serial refresh retry expiry minTTL)`

After you have edited the zonefile you can check it with `named-checkzone zonename filename`.

To answer the main point of your question, yes you can do what you want in a single zone. A /24 or larger can be contained within a single zone, although it is usual to separate them out. For networks smaller than a /24 it's a bit trickier but doable (by using `CNAME`s).

Here's an example zone:

```
; Zonefile for 168.192.in-addr.arpa.
@               IN      SOA     ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                        2011121101      ; serial
                                1H      ; refresh (1h)
                                10M     ; retry (10m)
                                1W      ; expire (1w)
                                30M )   ; minimum (30m)

@               IN      NS      ns1.example.com.
@               IN      NS      ns2.example.com.

1.1             IN      PTR     host1-1.example.com.
2.1             IN      PTR     host1-2.example.com.

1.2             IN      PTR     host2-1.example.com.
2.2             IN      PTR     host2-2.example.com.

1.3             IN      PTR     host3-1.example.com.
2.3             IN      PTR     host3-2.example.com.
```

Have a look at the [BIND ARM](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.8/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.html) (Administrator's Reference Manual). This is the canonical reference for BIND.